# Tensorflow 2.0 fit() is not recognizing batch_size

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras

So I'm initializing a model as:

`model = tf.keras.utils.multi_gpu_model(model, gpus=NUM_GPUS)` and when I do `model.compile()` it runs perfectly fine.

But when I do `history = model.fit(tf.cast(X_train, tf.float32), tf.cast(Y_train, tf.float32), validation_split=0.25, batch_size = 16, verbose=1, epochs=100)`, it gives me error:

> OOM when allocating tensor with shape[4760,256,256,3] and type float
>   on /job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/device:GPU:0 by allocator GPU_0_bfc
>   [Op:Cast] name: Cast/

This code worked perfectly fine previously but not anymore with Tensorflow 2.0. I have 4760 samples in my training set. I don't know why it's taking the entire set instead of the batch size.

Comment: Don't use tf.cast with a numpy array, just do X_train.astype(np.float32)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`model.compile()` only does configure the model for training and it doesn't have any memory allocation.

Your bug is self-explained, you directly feed a large numpy array into the model. I would suggest coding a new data generator or `keras.utils.Sequence` to feed your input data. If so, you do not need specify the `batch_size` in `fit` method again, because your own generator or `Sequence`  will generate batches.